# What's the difference between DH and DHM?

Tags: diffie-hellman

Is DHM just Diffie-Hellman with Merkle added to the name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's the same.

Wikipedia [writes on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Name):

> In 2002, Hellman suggested the algorithm be called Diffie–Hellman–Merkle key exchange in recognition of Ralph Merkle's contribution to the invention of public-key cryptography (Hellman, 2002), writing:
>
> > The system...has since become known as Diffie–Hellman key exchange. While that system was first described in a paper by Diffie and me, it is a public key distribution system, a concept developed by Merkle, and hence should be called 'Diffie–Hellman–Merkle key exchange' if names are to be associated with it. I hope this small pulpit might help in that endeavor to recognize Merkle's equal contribution to the invention of public key cryptography.[7]